# Tab menu (a links) script and I don't know where to insert an action (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have this javascript code for switch between tabs:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        document.querySelector('#videos').pause();
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
      });
    });
```

Each tab have one different video with the same ID and class. I need to stop them when a click into another tab.

This script only works with the first time I click a tab "a-link".

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: with the same id?  It is completely wrong to have multiple controls with same id

Comment: Well... I have the same id but I can assign a different id to each video (they are only four). I was testing if with the same id they can be paused at the same time. I don't know how to assign querySelector to multiple id's

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    var lampara = document.getElementById("video01");
    var desplante = document.getElementById("video02");
    var filon = document.getElementById("video03");
    video01.pause();
    video02.pause();
    video03.pause();
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
   });
 });
```